# Add A New Outlook Mail Category

Tags: vb.net

How can I use VB.net to check if a mail category exists, and if not, create it?

I’m using Visual Studio to create a VSTO outlook add-in. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bunch of trial and error, this code worked:

```
        myOlApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
        Dim ns As Outlook.NameSpace = myOlApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")

        If IsNothing(ns.Categories("CATEGORYNAME")) = True Then
            ns.Categories.Add("CATEGORYNAME", 18)
        End If
```